# What does "linear unit" mean in the names of activation functions?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, terminology, activation-functions

Activation functions, in neural networks, are used to introduce non-linearity. Many activation functions that are used in neural networks have the term "Linear Unit" in their full form. "Linear unit" can be abbreviated as **LU**.

For example, consider some activation functions

> ELU  - Exponential Linear Unit
>
> ReLU - Rectified Linear Unit
>
> ................................................

Why does the function name contain the term "Linear Unit"? What is meant by **Linear Unit** here? Is it saying anything about the nature of function under consideration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at these graphics showing popular linear units (image taken from [Clevert et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07289v5.pdf)):
[image]

You can see that these functions are linear functions for $x > 0$, that's why they are called *Linear Units*.

For example, the ELU is defined as

$$ ELU(x) = \begin{cases} 
x &\text{if } x > 0\\
\alpha (\exp(x)-1) & \text{if } x \leq 0.
\end{cases} $$
These functions introduce the nonlinearity around zero, each in its own way, which can be used for different problems.